# Convert or wrap h264 file to mp4 with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, mp4, h.264

I am taking video on a Raspberry Pi and am looking to convert the raw h264 file to an mp4 file or maybe wrap it in an mp4 as is done using the command line/Python. I however, am looking to do this in NodeJS. There seem to be many node JS libraries that use the Raspberry Pi's mp4-box library on npm. However, none of them have proper documentation or seem to fit the needs of my project. I do not know If I am missing something or if this is impossible.

Comment: Are you saying you just need to save the recorded video?

Comment: @Archer the video is saved as an h264 file but imgur, where I want to upload the video, does not except that file type nor does the library I want to use to convert the h264 to a gif. so mp4 filetype would be much more preferable

Comment: Save it with an mp4 file extension.  H264 isn't a video format - it's a compression format.

Comment: @Archer raspberry pi forums  (I am using an r-pi camera) says the camera takes video in this format and if i change the extension it wont change the vid itself, it will still be h264. I actually tried this yesterday and when i downloaded the video to my PC and played it, it gave me an error saying the extension was wrong

Comment: It's at the point you save the file you need to tell it to save as mp4 then.  Like I said, h264 is just a compression format, so the file is being saved as something other than mp4, but it is not a h264 file.

Comment: @Archer so when i take the video and save the file, in my code if i make it video.mp4 instead of video.h264, it will save and play properly as an mp4?

Comment: It's definitely worth trying as it's most likely an mp4 file.  There are other containers that can contain h264 video, but mp4 is the most common.

Comment: @cdoern Have you tried this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/handbrake-js

Comment: @Archer windows media player says when i try to open the mp4 file: Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.

Comment: In that case you need to find out how to save the file as an mp4 after you've recorded it.  You don't need to convert it - just save it as the correct format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a direct way to embed a H.264 encoded file into a MP4 container without actually building the entire file structure from scratch. This *is* doable but in order to do that you would need to understand the mp4 container format (which is heavily based on the Quicktime MOV container) and build it using `TypedArrays` which result you can save out as a MP4 file (I created a [paste here](https://pastebin.com/raw/xJjVpd92) describing the container file structure).

An alternative approach is to spawn [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) from Node.js (or simply use that software directly) and provide the H.264 as input and save it out as a MP4 file. It's pretty straight forward. The command would be something like:

```
ffmpeg -i yourH264encodedFileHere -c:v copy mp4FileContainer.mp4
```

To run that from Node can use [`spawn`](https://devdocs.io/node%7E8_lts/child_process#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) (see example).

An alternative to this bare-bone approach is to install and use the [fluent-ffmpeg NPM module](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#installation) which does all the heavy lifting.

#### Example

```
var ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
var inFilename = "video.h264";
var outFilename = "video.mp4";

ffmpeg(inFilename)
  .outputOptions("-c:v", "copy") // this will copy the data instead or reencode it
  .save(outFilename);
```

A couple of notes:

- fluent can be picky with filenames (spaces etc.).
- FFmpeg needs to be preinstalled and available in the global path. If you don't want it to be, you can use the `ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(pathToFFmpegBin)` instead.
- To install FFmpeg on RPI, [this resource](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2014/11/13/installing-ffmpeg-for-raspberry-pi/) may be useful.

Comment: what would be an example of how to run the ffmpeg code using spawn? that seems like the simpler option

Comment: You can simply use one of the linked examples as a starting point, just replace the "ls" command with ffmpeg and the needed arguments. OR - as an alternative to this use the [fluent-ffmpeg NPM module](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#installation) which abstract the entire process.

Comment: would this work for using the fluent-ffpeg library?:                                             
`var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var command = ffmpeg();
ffmpeg('/home/pi/Videos/video.h264').format('mp4');
ffmpeg.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
})
// save to file
ffmpeg.save('/home/pi/Videos/testmovie.mp4');`

Comment: fluent-ffmpeg seems to not work at all on my rpi it keeps throwing errors such as  "ffmpeg.on is not a command" and when i tried to install ffmpeg it installed a really really old version

Comment: Updated answer with example. ffmpeg must be preinstalled (see link in answer). For RPI [this resource](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2014/11/13/installing-ffmpeg-for-raspberry-pi/) may be useful as well.

Comment: the program the an error saying the video.h264 file was not found to i need to specify directories for the input and output file?

Comment: You need to specify the location either relative to where you run your node script, or as a absolute path to the file (see note in answer. Also see [`path.resolve()`](https://devdocs.io/node~8_lts/path#path_path_resolve_paths) in the Node.js documentation). I believe I have given all information you need however to embed a h264 stream into a container file using node.

Comment: your answer worked but just a quick question, this should work going from mp4 to gif as well right?

Comment: when i make the initial file the video.mp4 and the output video.gif it says "Error:ffmpeg exited with code 1: "

Comment: See if [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality) help. If not you will need to open a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to install ffmpeg on my pi zero took over two hours and ended in an error, so here's an alternate method to wrap mp4s:

1. Install MP4Box

```
sudo apt install -y gpac
```

2. In your Node script, use `exec` to call the `MP4Box` command as how the [Raspivid docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspivid.md) say

```
import raspivid from 'raspivid';
import { createWriteStream, unlinkSync } from 'fs'
import { exec } from 'child_process'
import internal from 'stream'


// Helper: promisify streaming to a file
const streamToFile = (inputStream: internal.Readable, filePath: string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fileWriteStream = createWriteStream(filePath)

        inputStream
            .pipe(fileWriteStream)
            .on('finish', resolve)
            .on('error', reject)
    })
}

// Helper: promisify executing shell command
const execPromise = (command: string) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                doLogInfo(stdout)
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error.message)
                    reject(error)
                }
                if (stderr) {
                    console.error(stderr)
                    resolve(stderr)
                }
                resolve()
            })
        })
    }

// Driver
const getMp4FromRaspivid = async () => {
    // Record vid w raspivid
    const h264Path = './myVid.h264'
    const readVideoStream = await raspivid(VIDEO_OPTIONS) as internal.Readable;
    await streamToFile(readVideoStream, h264Path)

    // Wrap in mp4
    const mp4Path = './myVid.mp4'
    const execCommand = ['MP4Box', '-add', h264Path, mp4Path].join(' ')
    await execPromise(execCommand)

    // Delete h264
    unlinkSync(h264Path)

}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's really important to know mp4 (like mkv) is a container. You can add video, audio, subtitle "layer" to these containers. And H.264 is already a compressed format, it is not a raw video format.

Comment: okay, bear with me here, is there a way to "convert" this h264 to mp4 using node Js? because other libraries I amusing in my program require an mp4 format. or are you saying i can insert this h264 video into an mp4 container?